# qwebview search all visible text

Tags: c++, string, qt, web

how can I find a text from qwebview?
I convert the document to plain text and use `QString::comapare` to find.

```
ui->webView->page()->mainFrame()->toPlainText();
```

but the method is unable to find text inside something like `iframe`.

how can I search all visible text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt represents a web page as an hierarchy structure of frames. So you need to use a recursive search.

```
bool findText(QWebFrame* frame, QString text)
{ 
  if (frame->toPlainText().contains(text))
  {
    return true;
  }
  foreach (QWebFrame* child, frame->childFrames())
  {
    if (findText(child, text)) return true;     
  }
  return false;
}
```

Use:

```
bool result = findText(ui->webView->page()->mainFrame(), QLatin1String("Text to find"));
```