# How to get DOM innerText on QWebView?

Tags: javascript, qt, qwebview, innertext

How can I get all of document.body.innerText on QWebView? I use QT version 5.5.1.

For example,

html file to load

```
<script>
    document.write("hello world!");
</script>
```

and I want to get "hello world".

so, I tried like this on QT

```
QWebView *wv = new QWebView(this);
QWebFrame *frame = wv->page()->mainFrame();
frame->load(QUrl("file:// ~ file path ~"));
QString string = frame->toPlainText();
// then write string to file for checking
```

I expected the string is "hello world" but, there was nothing.
I searched and found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25176954/qwebview-search-all-visible-text), and I changed code like that, but there was still nothing.

Do I misunderstand toPlainText() perhaps? And how I can get DOM innerText on QT 5.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not leaving enough time for the page to update. It will take a moment for the HTML to load, let alone for the Javascript to get executed.

There's a couple of workarounds here:

1. Use a [QTimer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html) to wait a couple of seconds before calling `toPlainText()`. This is hacky because there's no way of knowing exactly how long to wait, but it would be adequate for demonstration purposes.
2. Update the Javascript code to send back a notification to your C++ code after `document.write()` is called. For example, you could do this via a WebSocket, or use [Qt WebChannel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebchannel-index.html).

Comment: thank you for your answer, but it's fail at step 1.
I try to insert sleep(2) - on unistd.h - before toPlainText, but there is no change. (If sleep function is not suitable at this situation, tell me plz. I will try again with QTimer.)

Comment: oh, It works when I try by loadFinished. I really appreciate to you. Thank you.